# Count values from all table view cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a simple cafe menu like tableView where you can add food and it will count total price. To count total price, all values(sumLabel) in cells must be summed. My problem is when i'm trying to count it, it counts only sum in particular cell, but when i click "+" in another cell it starting from 0 .
Steps I made:

1. Create empty array(var totalArr: [Int] = []) in MainViewContoller
2. Create instance of MainVC in CustomCafeTableViewCell
3. In func changeSum() append price to totalArr  and the problem occured here . screenshot included.

[image]

```
TableViewController here 

    protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func decreaseNumber(cell: CustomCafeTableViewCell, number: Int)
    func decreaseTotal(cell: CustomCafeTableViewCell, number: Int)
   }

class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    let minValue = 0
    var totalArr: [Int] = []
    
    let sumCount: UILabel = {
        let foodCount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 50))
        foodCount.textColor = .black
        foodCount.textAlignment = .center
        foodCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return foodCount
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        sumCount.text = "Sum: \(totalArr.reduce(0, +))"
        customView.addSubview(sumCount)
        tableView.register(CustomCafeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCafeTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.tableFooterView = customView
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "Salads"
        } else if section == 1 {
            return "Drinks"
        } else {
            return "Desserts"
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCafeTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 2 {
            return 50
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

TableViewCell here

```
class CustomCafeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var vc = MainViewController()
        
var foodPrice = 10
var totalSum = 0
    
static let identifier = "cell"
private var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
let minValue = 0

@objc func decreaseFunc() {
    changeQuantity(by: -1)
    changeSum(by: -foodPrice)
}
@objc func increaseFunc() {
    changeQuantity(by: 1)
    changeSum(by: foodPrice)
}

func changeQuantity(by amount: Int) {
    var quality = Int(foodCount.text!)!
    quality += amount
    if quality < minValue {
        quality = 0
        foodCount.text = "0"
    } else {
        foodCount.text = "\(quality)"

    }
    delegate?.decreaseNumber(cell: self, number: quality)
}

func changeSum(by amount: Int) {
    var sum = Int(sumLabel.text!)!
    sum += amount
    if sum < minValue {
        sum = 0
        sumLabel.text = "0"
    } else {
        sumLabel.text = "\(sum)"
        vc.totalArr.append(amount)
        print("sum to show \(vc.totalArr.reduce(0, +))")
    }
    delegate?.decreaseTotal(cell: self, number: sum)
}

private let foodLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.text = "food"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

private let priceLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

private let increaseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "plus.rectangle"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

private let decreaseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "minus.rectangle"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

private let foodCount: UILabel = {
    let foodCount = UILabel()
    foodCount.text = "0"
    foodCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return foodCount
}()

 let sumLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "0"
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(foodLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(priceLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(increaseButton)
    contentView.addSubview(foodCount)
    contentView.addSubview(decreaseButton)
    contentView.addSubview(sumLabel)
    
    priceLabel.text = "\(foodPrice) $"
    increaseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseFunc), for: .touchUpInside)
    decreaseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(decreaseFunc), for: .touchUpInside)

    foodLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foodLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
    decreaseButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 170).isActive = true
    foodCount.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: decreaseButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    increaseButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foodCount.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    sumLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: increaseButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Sum: 0 placed in UIView and added with tableView.tableFooterView

I don't understand why totalArr not saving values when selecting another cell

My goal - count sumLabel.text values in all cells and show in Sum:

Comment: Each call of `MainViewController()` creates a new, different instance. This is certainly not what you want. You have to connect the UI elements in the cell to a data model and do all the math in the main controller. Or – as you have a fixed number of cells – consider to use static cells.

Answer (score 1):

Each time a new cell is created it initialises its own `MainViewController` with a new `totalArr` which is why your sum is now zero.

A quick fix is to pass a reference of the `MainViewController` to the cell. Like so:

```swift
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCafeTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.vc = self
        return cell
    }
```

Now you probably don't want to do that as @vadian mentioned. Instead math should be done in the MainViewController or even better some other model type.

Now if you do choose to pass a reference like a described make sure to use `weak var vc: MainViewController!` otherwise you will end up with a retain cycle with the cell holding a reference to the VC and the VC having a reference to the table view, which holds the cells. Adding `weak var` creates a weak reference and ensures that automatic reference counting does not increment the count in this case.